# en el caso del lookandfeel cuando uso el codigo setUndecorated(true) no funciona?

Tags: java

Para quitar los botones salir, minimizar y maximizar uso `setUndecorated(true)` y no funciona Lo hice usando por interfaz de netbeans de la misma manera no funciona como puedo resolver ese problema gracias de antemano.

***Nota:***
Utilicé el `NoireLookAndFeel` con jtatoo.

Comment: Vaya @Dalstron, acabo de descargar y probar ese LAF y pues si me funciona quitar la barra de título con ese método. De todas maneras en cuanto puedas por favor comparte mas detalles con el código fuente que llevas escrito.

Answer (score 0):

Te envio una muesta de como implemementar el look and feel en netbeans.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        NimRODTheme nt = new NimRODTheme();
        nt.setPrimary(new Color(153, 244, 51));
        nt.setPrimary1(new Color(133, 224, 31));
        nt.setPrimary2(new Color(143, 234, 41));
        nt.setPrimary3(new Color(153, 244, 51));
        nt.setSecondary(new Color(222, 230, 250));
        nt.setSecondary1(new Color(202, 210, 230));
        nt.setSecondary2(new Color(212, 220, 240));
        nt.setSecondary3(new Color(222, 230, 250));
        nt.setMenuOpacity(20);
        nt.setFrameOpacity(20);
        nt.setOpacity(20);
        NimRODLookAndFeel NimRODLF = new NimRODLookAndFeel();
        NimRODLF.setCurrentTheme(nt);
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(NimRODLF);
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new PRINCIPAL().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PRINCIPAL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Lo utilice numerosamente cuando utilizaba swing

Comment: el proble ma es que en el lookandfeel lo esconde y crean como sus prpios botones
cuando pongo false se puede notar

Comment: Usa este look and Feel es super configurable y nunca me fallo.  NimRODTheme